# WSO2 API Manager 4.1.0 failed to start control-plane

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I've downloaded the last version (4.1.0) of API Manager from the official website to upgrade an API manager 4.0.0 control-plane (distributed deployment) instance.

When I try to run the API manager with 'sh api-manager.sh' passing the '-Dprofile=control-plane' via command-line (like I do in 4.0.0 version), it always returns the following error 'Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender cannot be found by axis2_1.6.1.wso2v80':
[error_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnYt6.png)

(I've already tried to add the jar axis2-transport-tcp-1.0.0.jar to ../repository/components/droppins and it doesn´t work)

I've also tried to optimize the wsoam-4.1.0 installation for the profile I want to run (as suggested in the documentation), but in this situation a get a different error 'Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/inbound-endpoints/WebSocketInboundEndpoint.xml (No such file or directory)':
[error_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvebi.png)

Does anyone come across these errors? Is this a bug?
I can´t run an API Manager with the control-plane profile in 4.1.0 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CNF errors are expected when you start a profile without doing optimization. I assume you ran the optimization on the same distribution you used to start the profile initially and got the second error you have mentioned. You need to use a completely new distribution to avoid these errors.

1. Download and extract the product distribution.
2. Run the profile optimization (`sh profileSetup.sh -Dprofile=<profile>`).
3. Update the necessary configurations.
4. Start the server in the relevant profile (`sh api-manager.sh -Dprofile=<profile>`).

You can follow the recommended way mentioned in WSO2 documentation[1].

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/product-profiles/#starting-an-api-m-profile

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Yes, I've run the profile optimization before starting the service (on the same machine). This operation takes me to the error_2 ('Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .../repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/inbound-endpoints/WebSocketInboundEndpoint.xml).


--
Steps for the second error:
1. Unzip wsoam-4.1.0.zip
2. run 'sh api-manager.sh -Dprofile=control-plane --optimize --skipConfigOptimization' or 'sh profileSetup.sh -Dprofile=control-plane' + 'sh api-manager.sh -Dprofile=control-plane'

Comment: Actually, I have reviewed the steps, and if the process described is done in a fresh/new wsoam-4.1.0, it works (no errors). My mistake was to try to run it before the optimization. 
Once I've run it without doing the optimization it always haves the error_1 or error_2 described previously. (although this seems a problem because if I don´t do the optimization as the firsts steps, the installation seems to get inconsistent)